# Allow viewing articles by their tag in Stack Overflow for Teams

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-for-teams

In Stack Overflow for Teams, if I click on a tag underneath an article, I get taken to the "info" page about the tag, rather than seeing all articles containing that tag.

I'd prefer to have the latter occur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see all articles for a tag using the existing main search bar and this query:

**[tag-name] is:article**

I know it's not as pleasant as clicking the tag below an article, but it's a solution!